# Android Studio quitar titulo de toolbar

Tags: java, android-studio

Hola me gustaria saber como puedo quitar el titulo del toolbar

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/toolbarMenu"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="#00FFFFFF"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
   app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu2" />
```

Lo que no quiero es que el titulo de aplicacion final, no se vea, pero sin que se me vaya el menu deslizable que aparece al darle a las tres rayas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con:

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"     
        android:label="@string/app_name"     
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
```

Esto lo tendrías que poner en el AndroidManifest.xml

Eso debería de quitar el título en todas las activities, si lo que deseas es quitarlo en determinadas activities y no en todas, puedes probar con:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"/>
```